# Make flagged chat messages deletable regardless of edit window

Tags: feature-request, edits, chat, chat-flags

I just got a 30 minute ban from chat because one of my messages was flagged. I'm not here to argue about this - it happened, it won't un-happen and debating the rights or wrongs of it won't achieve anything, plus I am probably at least slightly on the wrong side of the line.

However, the message was not flagged (or at least I didn't notice) until after the 2-minute edit/delete window had expired. When I noticed it had been flagged, I attempted to delete it since I had clearly misjudged how it would be received, and if people find it inappropriate then they want it to be removed - presumably this is at least part of the point of flags.

I am proposing that flagged messages can be deleted by the OP when they are flagged regardless of the edit window, so that people who simply make a mistake can undo it.

Comment: Only dave can make a mistake and amass likes from it.  @mods give him what he wants

Comment: The problem there is that if deletion invalidates the flags and thus cancels out the 30min chat suspension if flags are validated then it could be abused to keep posting offensive content without consequence. If it doesn't invalidate the flag then nothing changes from now...

Comment: @JonClements Not quite: it would be removed immediately instead of waiting for others to validate/invalidate.

Comment: @LeviMorrison what I mean is if the flags are about to be validated can you self-delete and avoid the 30mins... Meaning you could then just repost rubbish again... Or would it validate the flags and message gets removed immediately and you still get the 30min...

Comment: @JonClements I understood you. My point is that the message can be removed *before* it validates. I'm not saying they shouldn't be banned, only that it makes it possible for the offensive content to be voluntarily removed sooner.

Comment: @JonClements that problem occurred to me after I posted this, a couple of things I can think of there; firstly it could perhaps be limited to, say, `flagCount <= 3` and secondly it does not necessarily need to invalidate the flag. Instead, other users could perhaps be informed that the post has been deleted when they are looking at the notification. I would say at least 50% of the time when I am looking at a flag, I will go visit the room to get the context in which the message was posted, I would hope that others also give it similar thought before validate/invalidate (except obvious abuse)

Answer (score 3):

What I would suggest is a "mea culpa" flag for your own stuff. You posted something and it didn't have the desired effect and now it needs to go. What it would do is notify you that you have a flag on your post and and let you delete it without a chat ban (goes away quicker). There would be a limit of, say, one per day network-wide to prevent abuse.

The root problem is that chat doesn't really have good tools for dealing with bad chat. You have one rollup flag for everything wrong, and mod flags (which are generally slow, since not all mods participate in chat). That's it. So, in this case, something potentially offensive was posted in a non-troll fashion but it couldn't be removed without either a sustained "bad" flag (with an automatic 30 min chat ban) or a mod deleting it. That's not a good way to handle things, and it took a mod to sort it out reasonably.

Comment: In some ways I'm less bothered about avoiding a ban and more bothered about resolving the issue quickly without disrupting the whole chat network. Often when something is flagged, the originating room will see an influx of users coming in to say "calm it down guys" in a way that can be disruptive in that room if a heavy on-topic discussion is in progress, and is certainly disruptive to users who are suddenly notified of an issue while they are busy with something else. The mods in general do a great job, but sometimes I feel like they get interrupted for stuff we could deal with ourselves.

Comment: Like in this particular case I was probably a bit out of line, I would argue that the ban was a little bit of overkill but I still accept it as a reasonable-ish penalty/reminder to behave. I just want to be able to clean up my mess I guess.

Comment: And that's where I approached it from. While I felt the comment needed deletion, I didn't feel it warranted a chat ban either (there's some mods who hang around chat who would have gladly deleted it on request), so I declined it and I suspect everyone who chimed in afterward also declined it for the same reason. There needs to be some kind of middle ground here beyond delete AND ban for regular users.

Answer (score 0):

#### There are too many problems with this feature request to consider implementing it.

While this seems like it'd be valuable for a small subset of users who inadvertently attract chat flags, I worry that users who intentionally post offensive content will use it to avoid punishment for their actions.

#### Consider:

Someone posts something offensive - they *know* it's offensive. They wait for a flag, delete it and then never get a chat suspension because they prevented it from ever getting flag deleted.

Why should we give users this opportunity to abuse their fellow chat companions? Yes, the post being removed is the important thing but it's also important to prevent users who regularly post abusive content actually get removed from chat.

With this feature, diamond moderators may never be aware of the situation if none happen to see the flag, which means that, unless a custom flag is raised, a user could repeatedly abuse someone and remove the flagged messages without the mods being the wiser.

There are a few other concerns

- Only users over 10K even see when a message is flagged. So, either this is a 10K+ *bonus* or there would have to be some sort of notification for everyone when their own messages were involved.
- Only users *currently* online would be able to do this. Some flags happen long after the conversation is over and the users have departed.
- It's a game of speed... how "bad" your comment is determines how quickly it accumulates flags. This seems... odd. Plus, a single flag is often never validated, so someone might delete a message that wasn't really problematic.
- Further abuse - "Someone flag this so I can delete it". Let's not.

I don't see this as being a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

So many potential problems here - Its probably a decent idea *if* people acted in general good faith, and rationally. You might, others might not. It also kinda works in that small window of time where you remember you said it, and someone notices (some flags are weeks, even months after the fact ._. Some people just want to see the world burn).

Lets say, *you said something you regret* - and you need it gone (after the edit/delete window), a clear "flag for moderator" might work, allowing you a chance for somewhat more gentle review by a mod. (Also, a mod can undo a suspension in specific cases).

And balancing "people messing up" (and with a 30 minute suspension - *this has happened before*), and people posting unwanted content is hard. Even the 5 minute edit/delete window gets abused massively by a few users.

Not sure this fixes anything broadly, and probably will result in people abusing it as a way to do a delete much after they post something.